# block internet access to AKS pods

Tags: azure-devops

I want to block internet access from AKS pods.

I wanted to try with blocking all egress by applying network policy to all pods. But not sure if that will be a good solution.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
```

Comment: fairly certain thats the only reasonable solution, why do you think its not good?

Comment: This solution will work fine as you haven't mentioned any rules in egress.